# How do I create a Tetris score counter using local storage and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, tetris

I'm trying to add a score counter to my Tetris game for my retro games website made completely out of JavaScript and html. how would I go about adding a score counter to my script?

I have tried multiple different ways even trying to use local storage but I just couldn't do it, could some one help me out?

```
let arena = [];

let rand;

const player = {
    pos: {x: 0, y: 1},
    matrix: null,
    color: null
}

rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * pieces.length);
player.matrix = pieces[rand];
player.color = colors[rand+1];

function drawMatrix(matrix, x, y) {
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j])
                ctx.fillRect(x + j, y + i, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}

function rotateMatrix(matrix, dir) {
    let newMatrix = [];

    for (let i in matrix)
        newMatrix.push([]);

    if (dir === 1) {
        for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                newMatrix[j][matrix.length - i - 1] = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                newMatrix[matrix.length - j - 1][i] = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return newMatrix;
}

function collides(player, arena) {
    for (let i = 0; i < player.matrix.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < player.matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (player.matrix[i][j] && arena[player.pos.y + i + 1][player.pos.x + j + 1])
                return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

function mergeArena(matrix, x, y) {
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            arena[y+i+1][x+j+1] = arena[y+i+1][x+j+1] || matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

function clearBlocks() {
    for (let i = 1; i < arena.length-2; i++) {
        let clear = 1;

        for (let j = 1; j < arena[i].length-1; j++) {
            if (!arena[i][j])
                clear = 0;
        }

        if (clear) {
            let r = new Array(tWidth).fill(0);
            r.push(1);
            r.unshift(1);

            arena.splice(i, 1);
            arena.splice(1, 0, r);
        }
    }
}
```

**When I have finished adding to score to the game. I am going to add a leader board outside of local storage using a database, any suggestions on how?**

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be more specific - what precisely is going wrong? Also, if you have designs on eventually storing the data in a database, local storage is going to be no use for you as that's held entirely on users' computers.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a score for when each row of blocks in the game that are cleared in local storage and then send that over to  a database so i can make a leader board

Comment: OK so you need to interface with `localStorage` in your `clearBlocks()` function (presumably). As for the DB side, that's a much bigger consideration and will need to be a different question when you get that for. As a rule for SO, the more focused, pinpointed a question, the more likely to be answered. Don't be afraid to break a wider problem down into multiple tasks and, therefore, SO questions.